# Add Google Review Feed in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

we are a construction company and we want to manage google review that we get in our SharePoint online site.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Google Analytics [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/) which is a JavaScript library that allows you to easily create and embed a dashboard into a website (including a SharePoint site) within minutes.

Comment: how do we implement that in sharepoint online site?